# Bootstrap responsive column to row (like a TD rowspan)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

Is there any way possible to go from this at a large viewport:

[image]

to this at an xs viewport:

[image]

Or is this beyond the scope of the BS grid system - short of having to regenerate the content to include the nested grid?

The images are obviously not to scale, but it should be enough to get the idea of what I'm trying to do. Col 2 could even be above 3, 4, and 5. Doesn't matter either way.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out push and pull for bootstrap,might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get this done is to use 2 layouts, this way you have control over the layout/content per screen size.

Effectively the `hidden-*-up` & `hidden-*-down` classes allow you to show and hide elements based on screen-size.

You could define the large screens in one set of divs:

```
<div class="hidden-xs-down">
  <!-- layout for large screens -->
</div>
<div class=".hidden-sm-up">
 <!-- layout for xs screens -->
</div>
```

The disadvantage, you need to maintain 2 layouts, the advantage you have full control.

[See the bootstrap docs for more information](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Comment: Thanks. Thought maybe I was just missing something on the BS grid side. Since the content is being generate, I was hoping there was a way to do it w/o having to generate two separate code blocks...but I guess that's the only option.